# Who are these hitmen?

Tags: riddle

There are only 3 hitmen in the city.

Here is what each had to say:

---

### Perry

Don't be fooled by my size. Perry is the go-to name in this city for bringing about "timely endings." Not surprisingly, I'm the most commonly used hitman in the city, delivering reliable results for your everyday, average hit. Unlike other hitmen, I even offer many other types of services.

---

### Quentin

For those who need to go the extra mile to confuse authorities, I'm your man. After examining one of my crime scenes, investigators are left wondering exactly what happened, how and why. Although my methods are considered dubious by most, I always finish off my targets as specified.

---

### Ethan

Do you need to bring about an "elaborate termination?" I specialize in making bold statements and getting people's attention. Use my services and all survivors will think twice before crossing you again!

---

**Who are these hitmen?**

Comment: JLee = the new Travis Kindred. Impressive riddle!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm going to guess that these hitmen are

> Punctuation marks! Specifically, the three that end sentences.

Perry is

> A period, which is the most commonly used punctuation mark to end a sentence. The period offers other services as well, such as decimals (1.5) and ellipses (...).

Quentin is

> A question mark, which is commonly used to indicate confusion. What, how, and why are all questions that end with a question mark. Every time there's a question the question mark finishes the sentence as specified.

Ethan is

> An exclamation point! Exclamation points are used both to make bold statements and to grab your attention.

Comment: The first letter of each name matches the first letter of each punctuation mark's name too.

Comment: @mmking Not really: this mixes British and US names: 'period' but not 'full stop', 'question mark' but not 'interrogation point'.

Comment: @smci I'm pretty sure they are called the period, question mark, and exclamation mark in the US.

Comment: @mmking: I thought the US term was 'interrogation mark/point'?

Comment: @smci Well, I grew up in the US, and we never called it anything except the question mark. Maybe you are right. In that case, I really have to go butcher my elementary school teacher.

Comment: @smci: Midwest US reporting: have never heard of an "interrogation mark/point". I've always called it a "question mark".

Comment: Ok thanks @AndrewCoonce. mmking: please don't drag me into a murder inquiry, or we really will have an interrogation point ;-)